# Find changed entries in 2 Data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Excel sheets generated monthly containing user data from an app we pay licenses for. I need to find a list of users who were added this month and a list of users removed from last month's spreadsheet. I need to compare the Email column as this is the only unique column in my data

Last months DF

```
| UserName | Email | Type | Number Of Licenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Blue | joe@codeschool.co.uk | Admin | 1 |
| Rachel Green | racehel@codeschool.co.uk | User | 2 |
| Shirly Brown | shirley@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
| Jack Black | Jack@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
| Cheryl Stone | Cherylt@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
```

This month's DF

```
| UserName | Email | Type | Number Of Licenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Blue | joe@codeschool.co.uk | Admin | 1 |
| Rachel Green | racehel@codeschool.co.uk | User | 2 |
| Richard Red | Richard@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
| Jack Black | Jack@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
```

Desired Outputs
DF_Added

```
| UserName | Email | Type | Number Of Licenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Richard Red | Richard@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
```

DF_Removed

```
| UserName | Email | Type | Number Of Licenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cheryl Stone | Cherylt@codeschool.co.uk | Adimin | 1 |
```

I tried several ways but can't get the desired output.

My current not working code

````
```
LastMonth = Path.cwd() / "./tempwork/UserReport_June.xlsx"
ThisMonth = Path.cwd() / "./tempwork/UserReport_July.xlsx"
df_LastMonth = pd.read_excel(LastMonth)
df_ThisMonth = pd.read_excel(ThisMonth)
df_changed  = pd.merge(df_LastMonth, df_ThisMonth, on="Email", 
how='outer', indicator='Exist')
df_changed  = df_changed.loc[df_changed['Exist'] != 'both']
df_changed.to_excel("./tempwork/changed.xlsx")
```
````

Comment: what is the error you are getting? or just not getting the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.merge` with `indicator=` parameter. Then use `left_only`/`right_only` indicator to filter rows that were added/removed. E.g.:

```py
x = pd.merge(df_last, df_current, on='Email', how='outer', indicator=True)

# added
added = x.loc[x['_merge'] == 'right_only', ['Email', 'UserName_y', 'Type_y', 'Number Of Licenses_y']]
added.columns = [c.split('_')[0] for c in added.columns]

# removed
removed = x.loc[x['_merge'] == 'left_only', ['Email', 'UserName_x', 'Type_x', 'Number Of Licenses_x']]
removed.columns = [c.split('_')[0] for c in removed.columns]

print(added)
print(removed)
```

Prints:

```
                      Email     UserName    Type  Number Of Licenses
5  Richard@codeschool.co.uk  Richard Red  Adimin                 1.0

                      Email      UserName    Type  Number Of Licenses
2  shirley@codeschool.co.uk  Shirly Brown  Adimin                 1.0
4  Cherylt@codeschool.co.uk  Cheryl Stone  Adimin                 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your question means you need the rows that exist in first dataframe but not in the second (those are whom unsubscribed), and  also the rows that exist in the second dataframe but not in the first (those are whom newly subscribed), so to do this task we can do it as:

```
# Find rows in df1 that do not exist in df2
un_subscribed_users = df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1.columns), how='left', indicator=True)
un_subscribed_users = (un_subscribed_users[un_subscribed_users['_merge'] == 'left_only']).drop(columns=["_merge"])

print(un_subscribed_users)

# Find rows in df2 that do not exist in df1
subscribed_users = df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1.columns), how='right', indicator=True)
subscribed_users = (subscribed_users[subscribed_users['_merge'] == 'right_only']).drop(columns=["_merge"])

print(subscribed_users)
```

just tweak / change `on` parameter to only the field you wish to compare records with.

Comment: A small comment on your writing style: Stack Overflow strives to be a professional knowledge base. Things as "Hope this helps" and "Welcome to the community", however friendly, aren't supposed to be in answers. Second, in English there's no white space before any punctuation (commas, dots, question/exclamation marks etc). See the [tour] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need added or removed susbscribers from the list.

So here I fist create the list with total subscribers from last month and this month and then kind of subtracted from the total to get the new added of removed. Filtered with isin.

```
one_df = pd.read_csv("one.csv", sep="|")
two_df = pd.read_csv("two.csv", sep="|")

total = pd.merge(one_df, two_df, how="outer", on="Email")
added_df = total[~total["Email"].isin(one_df["Email"])]
removed_df = total[~total["Email"].isin(two_df["Email"])]
print(added_df)
print(removed_df)
```

Based on added and removed list you can find out if anything is changed or not.